# How to set tabindex on html.actionlink in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tabindex

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application and i want to set tabindex on Html.Actionlink.

But i am unable to do that.

How can i set the tab index on html.actionlink in ASP.NET MVC4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name ", " ActionName ",new { @tabindex= 1 })
```

also you can try

$("#hyperlinkID").attr('tabindex','1');

Comment: Its not working.Also i have tried new{tabindex=1} and its not working too.

Comment: try this one $("#hyperlinkID").attr('tabindex','1');

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "ActionName ", null, new { TabIndex = 1 })
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer would be much more valuable if you could format the code properly and explain why/how it would solve the problem explained in the question.